# Unreported exception ...... must be caught or declared to be thrown; despite *thrown* keyword

Tags: java, netbeans, exception

I have a method being defined as:

```
private void startUSSDNotification(SimpleReference reference,
                                   String ussdServiceActivationNumber,
                                   String criteria)
    throws PolicyException {
    // Note that the injected javax.xml.ws.Service reference as well as port objects are not thread safe.
    // If the calling of port operations may lead to race condition some synchronization is required.
    USSDNotificationManager port = service.getUSSDNotificationManager();
    port.startUSSDNotification(reference, ussdServiceActivationNumber,
                               criteria);
}
```

The compiler whines that, "unreported exception PolicyException; must be caught or declared to be thrown. I don't know why it suggested I could throw yet "throws" is right there in the method signature.

`startUSSDNotification` is defined as:

```
public void startUSSDNotification(
    @WebParam(name = "reference", targetNamespace = "http://www.csapi.org/schema/osg/ussd/notification_manager/v1_0/local")
    SimpleReference reference,
    @WebParam(name = "ussdServiceActivationNumber", targetNamespace = "http://www.csapi.org/schema/osg/ussd/notification_manager/v1_0/local")
    String ussdServiceActivationNumber,
    @WebParam(name = "criteria", targetNamespace = "http://www.csapi.org/schema/osg/ussd/notification_manager/v1_0/local")
    String criteria)
    throws PolicyException, ServiceException
;
```

When I try to wrap the call in try...catch the error stays and it brings up another error that says the Exception is never thrown in the body of the try. How can I remedy this? Am using javase7 and netneans 8

Comment: May be what you thrown at method level exception package is different than the expected package. Have a broad eye on the package name for PolicyException class!!

Comment: Yes, I was importing from the wrong package. Fixed it now, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have not shown us the actual compilation errors, etc, I can't be sure, but I suspect that there are multiple classes called `PolicyException`, and that you are declaring the wrong one:

- Check the precise wording of the compilation error(s)
- Check your `import` statements.

Comment: Thanks @Stephen C, I was importing the wrong "PolicyException". Could never have figured this out from that compiler message.