# What does "error: unreported exception <XXX>; must be caught or declared to be thrown" mean and how do I fix it?

Tags: java, compiler-errors, uncaught-exception, checked-exceptions

New Java programmers frequently encounter errors phrased like this:

```
"error: unreported exception <XXX>; must be caught or declared to be thrown"
```

where XXX is the name of some exception class.

Please explain:

- What the compilation error message is saying,
- the Java concepts behind this error, and
- how to fix it.

Comment: Please note.  This intended to be a canonical Q&A for this kind of question.  There are *many* (hundreds) of existing questions, but they either have "too much code" or the answers are too specific to the code.

Answer (score 8):

First things first.  This a compilation error not a exception.  You should see it at compile time.

<sup>If you see it in a runtime exception message, that's probably because you are running some code with compilation errors in it.  Go back and fix the compilation errors.  Then find and set the setting in your IDE that prevents it generating ".class" files for source code with compilation errors.  (Save yourself future pain.)</sup>

---

The short answer to the question is:

- The error message is saying that the statement with this error is throwing (or propagating) a *checked exception*, and the exception (the `XXX`) is not being dealt with properly.
- The solution is to deal with the exception by either:

  - catching and handling it with a `try ... catch` statement, or
  - declaring that the enclosing method or constructor `throws` it<sup>1</sup>.

<sup>1 - There are some edge-cases where you can't do that.  Read the rest of the answer!</sup>

---

### Checked versus unchecked exceptions

In Java, exceptions are represented by classes that descend from the `java.lang.Throwable` class.  Exceptions are divided into two categories:

- *Checked exceptions* are `Throwable`, and `Exception` and its subclasses, apart from `RuntimeException` and its subclasses.
- *Unchecked exceptions* are all other exceptions; i.e. `Error` and its subclasses, and `RuntimeException` and its subclasses.

(In the above, "subclasses" includes by direct and indirect subclasses.)

The distinction between checked and unchecked exceptions is that checked exceptions *must* be "dealt with" within the enclosing method or constructor that they occur, but unchecked exceptions need not be dealt with.

(Q: How do you know if an exception is checked or not?  A: Find the javadoc for the exception's class, and look at its parent classes.)

### How do you deal with a (checked) exception

From the Java language perspective, there are two ways to deal with an exception that will "satisfy" the compiler:

1. You can catch the exception in a `try ... catch` statement.  For example:

   ```
   public void doThings() {
       try {
           // do some things
           if (someFlag) {
               throw new IOException("cannot read something");
           }
           // do more things
       } catch (IOException ex) {
           // deal with it    <<<=== HERE
       }
   }
   ```

   In the above, we put the statement that throws the (checked) `IOException` in the body of the `try`.  Then we wrote a `catch` clause to catch the exception.   (We could catch a superclass of `IOException` ... but in this case that would be `Exception` and catching `Exception` is a bad idea.)
2. You can declare that the enclosing method or constructor `throws` the exception

   ```
   public void doThings() throws IOException {
       // do some things
       if (someFlag) {
           throw new IOException("cannot read something");
       }
       // do more things
   }
   ```

   In the above we have declared that `doThings()` throws `IOException`.  That means that any code that calls the `doThings()` method has to deal with the exception.  In short, we are passing the problem of dealing with the exception to the caller.

Which of these things is the correct thing to do?

It depends on the context.  However, a general principle is that you should deal with exceptions at a level in the code where you are able to deal with them appropriately.   And that in turn depends on what the exception handling code is going to do (at `HERE`).  Can it recover?  Can it abandon the current request?  Should it halt the application?

### Solving the problem

To recap.  The compilation error means that:

- your code has thrown a checked exception, or called some method or constructor that throws the checked exception, and
- it has not *dealt with* the exception by catching it or by declaring it as required by the Java language.

Your solution process should be:

1. Understand what the exception means, and why it *could* be thrown.  Read the javadoc for the exception and the method that throws the exception.
2. Based on 1, read *your* code and decide on the correct way to deal with the possible exception.
3. Based on 2, make the relevant changes to your code.

### Example: throwing and catching in the same method

Consider the following example from [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67867013)

```
public class Main {
    static void t() throws IllegalAccessException {
        try {
           throw new IllegalAccessException("demo");
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        t();
        System.out.println("hello");
    }
}
```

If you have been following what we have said so far, you will realise that the `t()` will give the "unreported exception" compilation error.  In this case, the mistake is that `t` has been declared as `throws IllegalAccessException`.  In fact the exception does not propagate, because it has been caught within the method that threw it.

The fix in this example will be to *remove* the `throws IllegalAccessException`.

The mini-lesson here is that `throws IllegalAccessException` is the method saying that the caller should *expect* the exception to propagate.  It doesn't actually mean that it will propagate.  And the flip-side is that if you *don't* expect the exception to propagate (e.g. because it wasn't thrown, or because it was caught and not rethrown) then the method's signature shouldn't say it is thrown!

### Bad practice with exceptions

There are a couple of things that you should avoid doing:

- Don't catch `Exception` (or `Throwable`) as a short cut for catching a list of exceptions.  If you do that, you are liable catch things that you don't expect (like an *unchecked* `NullPointerException`) and then attempt to recover when you shouldn't.
- Don't declare a method as `throws Exception`.  That forces the called to deal with (potentially) any checked exception ... which is a nightmare.
- Don't squash exceptions.  For example

  ```
  try { 
      ...
  } catch (NullPointerException ex) {
      // It never happens ... ignoring this
  }
  ```

  If you squash exceptions, you are liable to make the runtime errors that triggered them much harder to diagnose.  You are destroying the evidence.

  Note: just *believing* that the exception never happens (per the comment) doesn't necessarily make it a fact.

### Edge case: static initializers

There some situations where dealing with checked exceptions is a problem.  One particular case is checked exceptions in `static` initializers.  For example:

```
private static final FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream("foo.txt");
```

The `FileInputStream` is declared as `throws FileNotFoundException` ... which is a checked exception.  But since the above is a field declaration, the syntax of the Java language, won't let us put the declaration inside a `try` ... `catch`.  And there is no appropriate (enclosing) method or constructor ... because this code is run when the *class* is initialized.

One solution is to use a `static` block; for example:

```
private static final FileInputStream input;

static {
   FileInputStream temp = null;
   try {
       temp = new FileInputStream("foo.txt");
   } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
       // log the error rather than squashing it
   }
   input = temp;   // Note that we need a single point of assignment to 'input'
}
```

<sup>(There are better ways to handle the above scenario in practical code, but that's not the point of this example.)</sup>

### Edge case: static blocks

As noted above, you can catch exceptions in static blocks.  But what we didn't mention is that you *must* catch checked exceptions *within* the block.  There is no enclosing context for a static block where checked exceptions could be caught.

### Edge case: lambdas

A lambda expression (typically) should not throw an unchecked exception.  This is not a restriction on lambdas *per se*.  Rather it is a consequence of the function interface that is used for the argument where you are supplying the argument.  Unless the function declares a checked exception, the lambda cannot throw one.   For example:

```
List<Path> paths = ...
try {
    paths.forEach(p -> Files.delete(p));
} catch (IOException ex) {
    // log it ...
}
```

Even though we appear to have caught `IOException`, the compiler will complain that:

- there is an uncaught exception in the lambda, AND
- the `catch` is catching an exception that is never thrown!

In fact, the exception needs to be caught in the lambda itself:

```
List<Path> paths = ...
paths.forEach(p -> {
                      try {
                          Files.delete(p);
                      } catch (IOException ex) {
                          // log it ...
                      }
                   }
             );
```

<sup>(The astute reader will notice that the two versions behave differently in the case that a `delete` throws an exception ...)</sup>

### Edge case: two exceptions called Xyzzy

I have seen cases where a method has a `throws Xyzzy` clause, and the compiler *still complains* that `Xyzzy` must be "caught or declared to be thrown".  For example: [Unreported exception ...... must be caught or declared to be thrown; despite *thrown* keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27100099).

If you find yourself in this situation, look carefully at the fully qualified names of the exceptions. If the fully qualified names are different, then the exceptions are different.  (Believe what the compiler is saying and try to understand it.)

### More Information

The Oracle Java Tutorial:

- [The catch or specify requirement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catchOrDeclare.html)
  ... also covers checked vs unchecked exceptions.
- [Catching and handling exceptions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/handling.html)
- [Specifying the exceptions thrown by a method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/declaring.html)