# image4j is ICODecode.read is throwing IOException

Tags: java, image4j

When using `ICODecoder.read(new File("path"));` in IntelliJ IDEA the read is underlined in read and states *"java: unreported exception java.io.IOException; must be caught or declared to be thrown"* in the build output. How can I fix this?

```
import net.sf.image4j.codec.ico.ICODecoder;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.List;

public class GUI {
    public GUI() {
        List<BufferedImage> imageList = ICODecoder.read(new File("path (it's  a proper, valid file path in the actual code)"));
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new GUI();
    }
}
```

image4j is downloaded from the official site and added as a dependency.

Comment: Welcome! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/908672/why-do-i-get-exception-must-be-caught-or-declared-to-be-thrown-when-i-try-to should answer your question - if not, please [edit] your question to elaborate. In short - you need to either catch the exception and do something about it, or mark your constructor as `throws IOException` and make the caller of the constructor do something about it.

Comment: @nanofarad I can't seem to find the answer to this issue in that question (by that I mean I don't know how to prevent this exception)

Comment: Sorry, I pasted the wrong link - please try https://stackoverflow.com/q/72751842/1424875 for a longer explanation (compared to the tl;dr in my previous comment)

Comment: Thanks, that was really helpful, before this I submitted an edit for review and reopening,  is there any way I can cancel that now? (I'm new to Stack overflow)

Comment: I don't think there's a need to cancel it (and I'm not sure how to cancel it either); worst case nothing will be done when a reviewer hits it. Thanks and welcome again!